# Is the definite article necessary in "one of the only two stores"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> That place is one of only two stores in the US that sell those things.
>   That place is one of **the** only two stores in the US that sell those things.

Since the context is clear and the stores are specified, it sounds to me the sentence with or without the article doesn't make much of a difference. Is the article optional in this case? Does it make a difference in meaning?

Comment: To my BrE ears there is no difference. If I were writing it, I would not use the definite article. You could actually lose the 'only' and still retain the meaning but possibly lacking the wow factor of there only being two stores in the whole of the US where you can buy them (whatever they are).

Comment: I agree with Jeremy. Editors do not like stuff that is not necessary. Bear in mind that had their been a previous discussion, their could be justification for overkill.

Comment: @JeremyC -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @JeremyC -- The word "only" makes another difference, as well.  "There are two stores" is ambiguous.  It could mean either "There are at least two stores", or "There are only two stores".

Comment: @Jasper but it is not ambiguous if we have '...is one of two stores in the US...'. That tells us that there are only two.'

Answer (score 2):

There are several different ways you can say it

> That place is **one of only two stores** in the US that sell those things.
>   That place is **one of two stores** in the US that sell those things.
>   That place is **one of the two stores** in the US that sell those things.
>
> **Only two stores** in the US sell those things, that place is **one of them**

"***Only***" may be used for emphasis

> one of **only** a handful
>   one of **only** two stores

Answer (score 0):

Both of the sentences convey the same information, but using article "the" in this situation is preferred since it emphasizes on the uniqueness of the store in the country.